# How to make MultiTrigger fire only when both properties change in TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have the following `MultiTrigger` defined:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsExpanded" Value="true" />
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ItemsPresenter.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                    From="0"
                    To="1"
                    Duration="0:0:0.2" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

I believe it fires whenever both `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` are `true`. Right now, it is firing whenever `IsExpanded` is already `true`, but `IsSelected` *changes* to `True`. I need it to fire whenever *both* of the properties *change* to true. How can I do this?

Comment: When you say *both*, do you mean *either*? In other words: Should it be enough that only one of `IsExpanded` or `IsSelected` is true to fire the trigger?

Comment: No, I mean _both_. The important bit is that I need it to fire whenever both _change_ to `true`.

Comment: Not sure you can do that in XAML, because you need to track "previous" states for comparison.  Here, you're just checking the current state, so you don't know anything about what changed.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, does the DependencyProperty `IsExpanded` have any sort of `OnPropertyChanged` event that fires when its value changes? I forgot to mention these DependencyProperties are attached to the `TreeViewItem`.